# where can i start task on SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mvvm

I am new of SwiftUI,I need do something when login button clickd,where should I use task,like this

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @State var loading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("login") {
            Task {
                try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000_000)
                 loading = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or this

```swift
@MainActor
class LoginViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var loading = false
    
    func login(){
        Task {
            try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000_000)
             loading = true
        }
    }
}
```

I know where should i use task on view init

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @State var loading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("login") {
            Task {
                try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000_000)
                 loading = true
            }
        }.task {
            //do something when view init
        }
    }
}
```

but i do not konw where should i use task when button tap

Comment: Ideally your view model should contain the logic that will handle loading, network requests etc. Placing your task inside a function inside your LoginViewModel seems like a good spot for it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, have the view model (`LoginViewModel`) handle the
processing tasks. To link that to the UI, use your `ObservableObject`,
as shown in the example code:

```
@MainActor
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loading = false  // <-- initially not loading
    
    func login() {
        Task {
            loading = true   // <-- is loading
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))
            loading = false  // <-- finished loading
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var loginModel: LoginViewModel  // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        if loginModel.loading { ProgressView() } // <-- for testing
        Text(loginModel.loading ? "loading" : "not loading")
        Button("login") {
            loginModel.login()  // <--- here do the Task
        }.task {
            // do something when view init
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var loginModel = LoginViewModel()  // <--- here

    var body : some View {
        DetailView()
            .environmentObject(loginModel)  // <--- here
    }
}
```